# MongoDB Atlas and real time sync from on premise DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a project which has the following characteristics:

- Local MongoDB replica set on an on-premise database
- Cloud MongoDB instance in MongoDB atlas
- On-premise MongoDB should keep in sync with MongoDB atlas
- Local MongoDB instance may be offline several days
- Once its online, it should start synchronizing with MongoDB atlas

Basically, I'm looking for something similar to Realm, except that this solution runs on an actual local server and not a mobile device.

I have looked into live migrations, [see here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/live-import/). But this doesn't seem to fit this use-case entirely, as its intended for an eventual cutover, which I don't want.

Therefore, how can I achieve the following with MongoDB atlas? What am I missing?

Can I treat MongoDB atlas, as if its a part of my local replica set, and use the standard replication capability of MongoDB? I.e. Atlas will always be a secondary.

Comment: How atlas can be "always secondary" if your on-prem "always primary" can go off for several days? Besides no replica set will allow such a downtime for its members. Something like coachdb would be more suitable for the job.

Comment: You've got a point.. Does that mean, MongoDB doesn't support this use-case? I.e. it doesn't support synchronizing data to Atlas regularly from a local database that changes between being offline and online.

Comment: I doubt it is possible to have replica set members in both Atlas and on-prem even if both are always on. Offline members is a separate issue. As I said whilst couchdb replication mechanism and conflict resolution is designed to address long downtimes for its members Mongo is more focused on performance and low latency. Members who are offline for more than 10 seconds require full "add a member to replica set" sync routine to join the set again. Depending on size of your database base it may take anything from seconds to hours and may significantly stress network (think about AWS bills)

Comment: Right - But again, when you mention AWS, it is a big + that MongoDB has global availability. It seems as if setting this up with CouchDB is not as easy.
Anyway, what you are saying is, that if I want to replicate data from a local MongoDB server to MongoDB atlas, I will have to write custom code to take care of this. While CouchDB is built to take care of this replication (regardless of how long the server has been offline)

Comment: That's right. Just to make it clear, couch is just one of the option off the top of my head. My 2 points are Mongo as a database is not intended for long offline members and Atlas as a managed db service does not allow external replica set members. At least not as a standard offer. Try to talk to their sales team if they can provide a quote for such requirement.

Comment: I have just read the documentation on CouchDB. It seems like a solid choice - And it integrates with IBM Cloudant, which is good.. Thank you very much @AlexBlex

Answer (score 0):

This functionality with native MongoDB Atlas not possible. You need to look for customised solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for `mongosync`. It migrates data from one cluster to another and can keep the clusters in continuous sync (MongodDB 6.0+ and M10+).